# Defining append using foldr

Tags: haskell

I have seen that it is possible to define the `append` function in Haskell in this way

```
append :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
append = flip (foldr (:))
```

I am looking for an explanation of how this works. My main problem is I don't know how `foldr` gets the lists as arguments. A full explanation of the entire implementation would be good though.

Answer (score 6):

`foldr` needs three arguments: an accumulator function, an initial accumulator value, and a list (well, a Foldable).

`foldr (:)`, therefore, requires two more arguments: initial accumulator, and list.

What is being done here, is cleverly using one of the two lists as the initial accumulator.

Then, for each element in the other list, it is cons'ed to the initial list; which results in all the elements in the other list being appended to the initial list.

Basically, `append [1,2,3] [4,5,6]` here is equivalent to `foldr (:) [4,5,6] [1,2,3]`, which ends up doing `(1:(2:(3:[4,5,6])))`, resulting in `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

Answer (score 3):

[**`flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:flip) is implemented as:

> ```
> flip                    :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
> flip f x y              =  f y x
> ```

So it is given a function `f` and two parameters `x` and `y`, and it applies these arguments like `f y x`. So that means that the `append = flip (foldr (:))` is short for:

```
append :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
append xs ys = foldr (:) ys xs
```

Now you can see `foldr` as a [*catamorphsim* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism) for a list. Indeed, for `foldr f z ls`, it replaces the cons `(:)` in the list of `ls` with `f`, and the empty list `[]` with `z`. For lists `foldr` is [implemented as](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#foldr):

> ```
> foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
> foldr k z = go
>     where go []     = z
>           go (y:ys) = y `k` go ys
> ```

So that means for `foldr (+) 0 [x1, x2, x3]` which is equal to `foldr (+) 0 (x1 : (x2 : (x3 : [])))`, it is equal to `x1 + (x2 + (x3 + 0))` or less verbose `x1 + x2 + x3 + 0`.

So here for `foldr (:) ys`, with a list `[x1, x2, x3]`, this is equal to `(x1 : (x2 : (x3 : ys)))`, which is thus equal to a list of `[x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, …, yn]`.

Answer (score 1):

`flip f xs ys = f ys xs`, so then

```
append xs ys = flip (foldr (:)) xs ys 
             = foldr (:) ys xs
```

Now, `foldr g z xs` replaces every `:` in `xs` with `g`, and it replaces the final `[]` in `xs` with `z`, so we get

```
append (x1 : x2 : ... : xn : []) ys = foldr (:) ys xs
                            -- replace `:` with `:` and `[]` with `ys`:
  =    (x1 : x2 : ... : xn : ys)
```

As to where it gets the lists from, they are simply left *implicit*. Haskell allows to shorten a definition by removing the same last parameter from its left hand side, and its right hand side, if it's not needed in what remains:

```
    foo x y z = g x x y z
    foo x y   = g x x y 
    foo x     = g x x  
              = join g x
    foo       = join g
```

`x` can't be simply removed, as it is needed in the remaining `g x`. But after transforming it with the use of `join` (details of what it is and why it works don't matter here) it becomes possible to remove the remaining `x` as well.

In your case the arguments are used just once, and their order is flipped by using the `flip` function:

```
    append xs ys = foldr (:) ys xs
                 = flip (foldr (:)) xs ys
    append xs    = flip (foldr (:)) xs
    append       = flip (foldr (:))
```